# Can we use partition by and group by together in teradata?

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a select query that looks like below :

```
   sel aa.*
    , min(Case when  BAL   >0           then       1
    when bb.CUST_DT  < aa.APPL_DT  then            2
    else                                           3
    end)  
    over (partition by app_id)     as cus_Typ
    from 
     tablea AS aa
      left join tableb      as        bb
    on aa.cust_num=bb.cust_num
    group by 1,2,3
```

I see the following errors when running it.

1. The error I get if I remove the 'cus_Typ' (Group by col 3) in the group by clause is

3504 Selected non aggregate values must be part of associated group

2. If I add the cus_Typ (since it is in the partition/ranking clause),
   I get the error below:-

Error 5481- Ordered analytical functions are not allowed in the group by clause

Scenarios when the code runs just fine:-

1. Without the partition the group by is working just fine. With the partition it throws an error..
2. Without the group by partition works fine.

My question is how can we make this query work by including both group by and partition ? What columns need to be included in the group by?

Thanks.

Comment: When using  window functions like that, you don't need to specify a group by clause. Show some sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thank you! @Andrew! I was under the same impression but needed someone to validate  that. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: OLAP-functions are processed *after* aggregation. If you use them in combination with aggregation you can access all columns in GROUP BY and aggregated columns only.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the working options

```
select 
  column_1 
  , count(*) over(partition by column_1 order by column_1)  -- will give you "1" in this specific case
  , count(*)                 -- number of occurences of each column_1 values     
  , count(*) over()          -- will give you number of unique column_1 values
  , sum(count(*)) over ()    -- will give a total number of rows in the dataset
from  
  table_1
group by
  column_1
```

Doubling partition and group by doesn't seem to work, if you are trying to run it across different columns.